# NSNumber returns wrong value

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary, nsnumber

I have `NSDictionary` and I assign value of 'price' key to `NSNumber` property of my object but when I log number value, it is an strange negative number!

```
item.price = [food valueForKey:@"price"];
```

price property is `NSNumber`

```
[[food valueForKey:@"price"] class]
```

will print `__NSCFNumber` which is right.

```
[[food valueForKey:@"price"] intValue]
```

returns `0x000000000000c350` which is `50000` thats right

but when I log `item.price` or `[item.price integerValue]` it is `-15536` which is completely wrong!

Any idea?

food json sample:

> {
>   "title":"Pizza",
>   "price":50000
>   }

[image]

Comment: How do you "log" `item.price`?

Comment: What is `item` and what is `food` ?

Comment: item is `NSManagedObject` representation of food `NSDictionary`

Comment: food must be a dictionry!!!

Comment: may be i should say ,it is a dictionary!!!! I have no strong reason to say it must be a dictionary!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Guess what?

all of this logs and problems shows my NSNumber property can't store some integers. but what range of integers? integers which are between `-32,768 / 32,768`

but why? because I have define my managed object `price` property of kind `NSInteger 16`!

I should define it as `NSInteger 32`

Comment: awesome answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you are trying to do this:

```
NSDictionary *inventory = @{
                                @"price" : [NSNumber numberWithInt:50000]

                                };
    NSNumber *num= [inventory valueForKey:@"price"];

     NSLog(@"%d,%f,%ld,%@",num,num,num,num);
```

and the log will display as:

```
 800002,-0.000000,-5764607523033434878,50000
```

all of them are totally different.The last one is the correct `NSNumber` object

`NSNumber` is an object ,so you need to use %@ to log it and remaining %d,%f,%ld are not objects.

Comment: see the updated photo! even with NSLog(@"%@", num) returns wrong number

Comment: Can you do po item and show us the contents in item ?

Comment: can you try to convert your managed object to dictionary and check?

Comment: NSDictionary *dict = [item dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:keys]; and try to log dict

Comment: strange! value for price in NSDictioanry is `-15536` here is how I convert to NSdictionary `NSArray *menuItems = [[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error] valueForKey:@"Foods"];`

Comment: you are making an array not a dictionary ,try to convert data to dictionary, Also please update your question with the latest info.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91631/discussion-between-hashem-aboonajmi-and-mr-t).